# Filebeat keys_under_root doesn't work for multiline

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

When I specify `json.keys_under_root: true` and

```
  multiline.pattern: '\s'
  multiline.negate: false
  multiline.match: after
```

at the same time, the payload is kept inside "message" and is not flattened out.
Without multiline configuration everything is properly flattened and I can see all keys from my application payload on root level of the json file generated by FilBeat

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow.

- `json.*` is used to decode logs structured as JSON messages, so you have a structured log format.
- `multiline.*` is to collect multiple lines of an unstructured log message.

How / why would you need to combine them? Maybe you can add a few lines of the log you're trying to collect to illustrate your use case and what you want to achieve.

Comment: surely, I will be able to add my logs on Monday. But in the meantime, you can check https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/configuration-filebeat-options.html#config-json . Check message_key description. It is used specifically for multilining and filtering.